# Functions to convert iterables (list, jsons, etc) in a dataframe to SQL friendly data types

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm working on pulling different tables of data from an API and inserting it into a SQL database (eventually upserting future API calls but for now not) using SQL Alchemy and Pandas dataframe. One problem I am trying to simplify is when pulling the JSON object I convert the initial JSON to a dataframe (that is what I will be inserting), but some of the columns of the DataFrame contain jsons/lists in them which makes them unable to be inserted into SQL. using df.apply I found a decent workaround; However, every api call from the API has a different amount of columns in each table, so manually finding which columns to convert to strings is tedious.. - is there any way to loop over every column and convert it to a SQL-friendly insert if it's a dict or list? Thanks!

Code:

```
def PullAndInsert(API, engine):
    #Get JSON data 
    data= API.getdata()
    #convert to data frame
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
    df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(ConvertDictToString)
    df['column2'] = df['column2'].apply(ConvertDictToString)
    df.to_sql('CloseReasons', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

edit: added some sample data :

| index | status | SourceData | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 221 | accepted | 'NotAJSONOrList' | 'NotAJSONOrList' |
| 347 | rejected | ['list', 'items', 'inside'] | {"key": "value", "id": 4001} |
| 222 | accepted | {"key": "value", "id": 4001} | ['list', 'items', 'inside'] |

Comment: `for col in df.columns: if '{' in df[col][0] or '[' in df[col][0]: df[col] = df[col].apply(ConvertDictToString)` <<< something like that? Hard to know exactly without some sample data.

Comment: @DavidErickson Thanks for the reply - just added some sample data. I tried that but the main issue is there is an edge case with some of the dataframes where the first row for a column may not be a JSON, and I get an error trying to insert a list/JSON type into SQL later.

Comment: `for col in df.columns: if df[col].dtype == 'object': df[col] = df[col].apply(ConvertDictToString)` In your `ConvertDictTyoString` function you might also have to include some error handling with `try`.